# Unauthorized response after setting CachePolicy with HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnet-httpclient

I am sending a `GET` request to a server which expects `NTLM` authentication.

For that we set `UseDefaultCredentials = true`

```
var defaultHandler = new WebRequestHandler
{
  UseDefaultCredentials = true,
  CachePolicy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpRequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore),
  AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip,
  AllowAutoRedirect = true,
  UseCookies = true,
  CookieContainer = new CookieContainer()
};
```

**Everything was working correctly until we decided to turn on Cache**.

For that we changed our `CachePolicy` to `CachePolicy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpRequestCacheLevel.Default)`

With that change the server started to respond with `401 - unauthorized` and is sending alongside the `WWW-Authenticate: NTLM`

Any ideas why setting the Cache changed the behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of the problem was that the server was responding with

`Cache-Control: private`

Our `HttpClient` was caching that response and thus, the following negotiation step was being served from `Cache` instead of being requested to the Server resulting on the failure to authenticate.

**We disabled caching** on `401` responses.
After a lot of reading we decided to implement it as [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#Preventing_caching) states

`Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate`